# Can I use geo fencing from room to room?

Tags: ios, geo

can I use iOS geo fencing methods from room to room within a house? or just for larger distances (eg 100metres?)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the method used (GPS / Wireless Lan / Mobile network cell) the accuracy is different.
GPS has 10meters (you can't use it inside normally), Wireless Lan just the position of your house / network router, the cell (GSM) has an accuracy of ~250meters.
 
Because of that it's not impossible to use it inside but you won't get any exact position of it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't!

GPS inside a house is so bad that it can show you a position any where 50m inside or around the house.
 And for your wireless routers, apple dont have the position, 
and further it could only work if you have multiple wireless routers at that house, and
implement that for yourself.

So it simply does not work.

Outside the house GPS will have approx 3-6m.

Comment: 3-6 m? This is extremely accurate for any iPhone, and I'd be impressed if you're actually able to get such accuracy. In general, within 50m is very good for iPhone (including outside the house)

Comment: GPS SW developpemnt is my profession. This is not extremly accurate, This is a standard Iphone 4, and any other GPS nowadays have this accuracy. iphone 3 is worse. Generally when having a bad view to sky it get worse.